# Get current page using PrawnPDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn

does anyone know if there is a method to get the **current page** on PrawnPDF for Ruby on Rails? I'm using `PrawnPDF (0.12.0)` with `Rails 3.2.9`. I've looked in the documentation, without success.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

```
Document.outline.page_number
```

Or

```
Document.page_number
```

May also work

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When using _Document_ it says that is an unitialized constant. In the controller i have this code: `pdf = ItemPdf.new(@item)`. So, how can i refer to it in the item_pdf.rb?

Comment: I actually don't see anything related to prawnpdf here, class ItemPdf should be declared somewhere in your project, and there will be the answer how Prawn:Document relates to this class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i was meaning was that when using Document.page_number it says that is an unitialized constant. That's why i explained what did i put in my controller. Any other idea for getting the page_number?

Comment: This is basics of object-oriented programming, `Document` is a [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)), a description of how all instances of this class will behave, what you want is to get a page number of an [instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)). You have an instance `pdf` of the class `ItemPdf`, which inherits class Document or includes it's instance as a property.

Comment: This should be declared somewhere in your program (in the block `class ItemPdf ... `, so you have to find out how `Document` relates to your `ItemPdf`, so you could access it like `pdf.page_number` or `pdf.something.page_number`.